# Postfix does not bind to localhost

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, smtp

I'm having the problem, that my Postfix service does not bind to 127.0.0.1 respectively localhost.
Everything works perfectly fine with the server, except that I cannot connect to it locally (which I need to do).

A quick look into `main.cf`:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1,localhost,82.51.166.126,1a01:448:36:1000:5c22:a6f2:0:1
```

which gets confirmed by `postconf`. I also tried the value `all`, it didn't change anything. After restarting Postfix, I check `netstat -tulpn | grep 587` and I get:

```
tcp        0      0 82.51.166.126:587       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3411/master
tcp6       0      0 1a01:448:36:1000:5c:587 :::*                    LISTEN      3411/master
```

There is no binding to localhost/127.0.0.1 or anything else which would allow that. I'm not sure if there is anything else to configure to make this work. Maybe something in `master.cf`? Any other ideas?

Comment: What about the default port, 25?

Comment: Exactly the same two entries for 25.

Answer (score 0):

Is your requirement to be able to send emails from that server? If so have you tried adding the line below to your main.cf file?

```
myorigin = yourdomain.com
```

JP

Answer (score 0):

Try to change mynetworks to `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8` and `inet_interfaces = all`